# Read rss by URL - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, url, rss, websphere, portlet

Hello I have a problem I want to consumed rss by URL that site and I can't do.
Example:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy.example.local");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "80");

DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

URL url = new URL("http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/");  
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
InputStream stream = url.openStream();  
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(stream);    
System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

Error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I need help for this search in IBM site and forums , and dont resolve the problem.
Greeting
João Sousa

Comment: you are declaring a variable twice. is this code compiling?

Answer (score 0):

If you can open http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/ trough your browser, you don't need that first two lines:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy.example.local");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "80");
```

There's no `proxy.example.local`.

And, of course, remove the line

```
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
```

The final code would be

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    URL url = new URL("http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/");
    InputStream stream = url.openStream();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(stream);
    System.out.println("Root element of the doc is "
            + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

It worked for me.